# Unable to upload file from $_FILES array in drupal7

Tags: files

I am trying to upload file from `$_FILES` array. but getting following error in drupal7.

```
The specified file temporary://fileOYnPHK could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured.
This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
```

The `sites/default/files` has permissions `777`

Here is my code

```
if($_FILES['files']['name']['field_tenant_review_ref_und_form_field_tenancy_document_und_0']){
    $file_path = file_save_data(file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['field_tenant_review_ref_und_form_field_tenancy_document_und_0']),
    'public://sites/default/files/'.$_FILES['files']['name']['field_tenant_review_ref_und_form_field_tenancy_document_und_0']);
   }
   //$tenant_review->field_tenancy_document->file->set($file_path);
```

Is there any mistake in code? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your **Public file system path** but with your **Temporary directory**; normally it is `/tmp` if you're in a Mac or Linux server.

You can check that the Temporary Directory is well configured, maybe it is pointing to a non-existing path.

To check the configuration in Drupal 7 you must go to *Configuration* > *Media* > *File system*.

Comment: Using Linux, The temporary directory is `sites/default/files/tmp`

Comment: @DevidasKadam, is that directory writable by everybody? I'd suggest to change it to `/tmp` and try again.

Comment: yes. it is writable by everybody.